# How can I make jQuery click on the currently selected radio option?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am trying to use jQuery to find which radio option is selected and then simulate a click using .click()

My current code is:

```
jQuery('form input[type=radio]:checked').click();
```

but it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by " _it is not working_ "? Does it throw some error? Does it work in a different way than you expect? Or the code is not even executed? Basically: what happens and what should happen?

Comment: It seems to work like so: http://jsfiddle.net/ER5Hu/

Comment: your code should work. try debugging it by adding jQuery('form input[type=radio]').click(function(){alert('it does work.'); });

Comment: Why would you want to click on a checked radio element? A click on a checked radio element does nothing...it certainly doesn't, and shouldn't, toggle the check; so what are you aiming to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a test case for you, where you can test if it actually works or not. It seems to work in the following setting in FF 7. http://jsfiddle.net/ER5Hu/

Perform the following steps:

- Click on the button: nothing happens
- Click on a radio button: you get an alert (by definition of the first jq-rule)
- Click on the button: you get an alert (by definition of the second jq-rule)

This is the html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="radio"/>hello
            <input type="radio"/>bye
            <input type="button" value="button" id="testbutton"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form input[type=radio]').click(function(){
        alert('clicking');
    });

    $('#testbutton').click(function(){
        $('form input[type=radio]:checked').click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Marnix. Your example confirms that it should work, which indicates that there must be a problem elsewhere in my code. With this knowledge I was able to quickly find the issue in another place. I feel a little silly, but at least now I know that I was using the correct method :) Thanks again.